# Periodos entre fechas laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, carbon

Tengo un sistema donde voy el usuario registra quincenas, ingresa la fecha de incio y la fecha fin de cada quincena.

Qusiera poder validar que al registrar una nueva quincena no exista una quinena registrada previamente en ese periodo de tiempo.

Es decir, si en mi BD tengo 2 quincenas las cuales son: 
1. fecha_inicio: 01-01-2019 fecha fin: 15-01-2019
2.fecha_inicio: 20-02-2019 fecha fin: 30-01-2019

Que no pueda registrar una quincena entre las fecha inicio y fecha fin, por ejemplo que NO sea posible registrar una quincena con fecha de inicio del 14-01-2019 al 19-02-2019.

Tenía pensado algo asi:

```
    $quincena=Quincena::where('fecha_inicio', '<=',$request->input('fecha_inicio'))->where('fecha_fin','>=',$request->input('fecha_fin'))->first();
```

Pero no me funciona, espero me puedan ayudar.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que las fechas no se deberían de comparar con el método `where`, considerando que tus fechas tienen un formato "Y-m-d" por ejemplo y que no es una fecha Unix como lo que devuelve la función `time()` de PHP, tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:

Arriba de tu clase, necesitarás importar Carbon:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

En tu método:

```
$fecha_inicio = new Carbon($request->fecha_inicio);
$fecha_fin = new Carbon($request->fecha_fin);


$quincena = Quincena::whereDate('fecha_inicio', '<=', $fecha_inicio)->whereDate('fecha_fin', '>=', $fecha_fin)->first();

if($quincena){
   //ya existe una registrada
}else{
   //no existe una quincena registrada
}
```